# When setting up a standard subversion server using /trunk /tags /branches Where do you store Program Documentation?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am setting up a brand new SVN Server.  All of our various projects have a doc file with information about the program.  If I set up my repository with the standard:

```
/projectA/trunk
/projectA/branch
/projectA/tags
```

Where do I store the program documentation?  Should I set up a seperate Repository for just Documentation?  Add a new sub directory /projectA/docs?

What is the standard?

Comment: Good question, I'm not sure if there is a standard. If it's a single document describing each project and branch-independent, then /projectA/docs seems fine. If it's a whole set of office document type files, you may consider a separate repository.

Comment: What kind of documentation are you talking about? Generated documentation like JavaDoc?

Answer (score 1):

To me, the documentation is part of the project. It should thus be in `/projectA/trunk/doc`, for example.

This way,

- if you create a feature branch, the new feature can be documented inside this branch, and this new documentation can be reintegrated in the trunk once the feature is finished, or be abandoned if the feature is abandoned
- if you create a maintenance branch, this maintenance branch will reference the documentation of the product as it was when the branch was created
- if you create a tag for version 1.0 and are now developing version 4.0, you can still refer to the tag to get back the documentation of the 1.0 release.

BTW, it's often a good idea to automate the creation of the documentation as part of the build of the project. Documentation is like source code.